Solana-test-validator airdrop request if failing due to being rate limited
$ solana config get
Config File: C:\Users\.config\solana\cli\config.yml
RPC URL: http://localhost:8899
WebSocket URL: ws://localhost:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: C:\Users\id.json
Commitment: confirmed

Above is the config setting, whenever I try to run a test validator and then request an airdrop , it always fail displaying the following message:
solana airdrop 2
Requesting airdrop of 2 SOL
Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.

I read a solution suggesting to use "solana airdrop 2 -ul" but even this is not working for me.

If you are on localnet you need to have the solana-test-validator running to request an airdrop, but this isn't really necessary as the validator is already initialized with 500000000 SOL you can use.
Make sure that the validator is initialized in another terminal tab or try running
solana-test-validator

The error you are getting is usually associated with the devnet and testnet cluster and happens when you've requested too much airdrops of the faucet is empty. Check back after a day to see if the response changes after and airdrop request.

I was running it on a seperate tab but was still getting the above mentioned issue but it solved automatically when I started using WSL
